# toast message I DON'T WANT TO SHOW. is it possible?

Tags: android, android-toast

My problem is: I need to pass present activity's context. and than toast message is shown. (when using external library that can not be edited)

When i pass my context. This always returns toast message.

But i don't want to show toast message.

Is it possible?

I'm using external [MultiImagePicker library](https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker)

here is my main code, just initialized. i do nothing.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Picker.Builder(this,new MyPickListener(),R.style.MIP_theme)
                        .setLimit(2)
                        .setPickMode(Picker.PickMode.MULTIPLE_IMAGES)
                        .build()
                        .startActivity();
    }

private class MyPickListener implements Picker.PickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onPickedSuccessfully(final ArrayList<ImageEntry> images)
        {
            for(ImageEntry image : images){
                Log.d("onPickedSuccessfully", "image.path #"+image.path);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(){
        }
    }
```

gradle(Module:app)

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/yazeed44/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0'
}
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The possible answer is that you can download the source code of library and do desired modifications.

Comment: thanks your tip. i will check here. https://dl.bintray.com/yazeed44/maven/net/yazeed44/imagepicker/imagepicker/1.3.0/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can go to the library, open that class and remove toast from the onCancel method().

```
 @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.i(TAG, "User canceled picker activity");
    }
```